# Running Apache Nutch on windows

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

I am trying to run Apache Nutch on Windows for web crawling.I have installed cygwin and set its Path .But I am getting the following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path:    \tmp\hadoop-cjindal\mapred\staging\cjindal-330065706\.staging to 0700
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkReturnValue(FileUtil.java:682)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.setPermission(FileUtil.java:655)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:509)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:344)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:189)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:856)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:850)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1083)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:850)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:824)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1261)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.inject(Injector.java:217)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.run(Crawl.java:127)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.main(Crawl.java:55)
```

I have not installed hadoop. Please help.

Comment: Nutch runs on hadoop and hadoop has issues with running on windows for setting of permissions to folders and other parts. Check for any unix flavour and your life would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to run Nutch on Unix. But if you want to run it on windows then probably you can download 1.2 version of Nutch which comes with Hadoop version which does not have this issue.